# Using Imagemagick commands in Automator with passed images

Tags: command-line, automator, image-editing

I am trying to make a workflow in Automator that takes video screenshots and ideally at the end montages them into one image.

I have the video shot working, and is saving into a timestamped folder, so the sequence runs and a folder with the current time stamp is saved 3 images Shot1.tiff, Shot2.tiff, Shot3.tiff into a folder.

I've installed Imagemagick and it's working if I browse to the folder in Terminal and run the montage command:

%> montage -geometry +4+4 Snap1.tiff Snap2.tiff Snap3.tiff montage.jpg

then I get just what I want - the output montage.jpg
However I'm trying to replicate this in Automator at the end of my 3 images - and that's what I'm struggling with - transferring this to a Shell script with the variables in Automator?

Answer (score 0):

Ive got this working (roughly) by hard-coding. The Script wants to pass the filenames individually to go round a loop for each file, but I want to hand them all together - I can do it by dumping all arguments at once, hard-coding the output file to the desktop then moving the output file. It's not pretty but variables into script is beyond me.

Comment: Can you add the code/commands you used for this? This would make it easier for others to learn from your experience.